# keeping data during orientation changes by using fragments

Tags: android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to understand fragments. All the examples I read is about having a main activity and then two sub fragments.
The issue is that my program has only 1 activity. Can I make it a fragment?
Current ui main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {}
```

Can I make it

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment {}
```

The program I am trying to create will constantly monitor phone variables and display logs in a textView. I don't want to lose the logs when the user changes the orientation or some other change when the os destroys the ui.

The UI is basically 1 textView that gets filled by a runnable that updates the textView every 5 seconds with the content of a linked list. I don't want to lose the content of the linked list basically.

I checked getLastNonConfigurationInstance() but it seems it's depreciated so I don't want to use that

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Amish

Comment: So after a lot of searching I found that if you add the following:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found answer here:
http://blog.webagesolutions.com/archives/458

So after a lot of searching I found that if you add the following: 
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

in the androidManifest.xml, the os will not destroy the activity when switching from portrait mode to landscape mode.

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.axr0284.phonecontrol"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.axr0284.phonecontrol.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Hope this helps somebody,
Amish